robocopy XD exclude does not seem to work sometimes
For example:
robocopy c:\folder d:\folder /MIR /ZB /FFT /MT:32 /R:10 /W:5 /NP /XD cache temp /sl /xj
I can clearly see it copying folders with "cache" and "temp" in it. (ie. c:\folder\chrome\default\code cache\js\blah)
I've tried different things:
/xd cache /xd temp
/xd cache /xd temp
/xd "cache" /xd "temp"
/xd "cache" "temp"
But /xd cache temp chrome seemed to work to exclude the whole chrome folder

Not a direct answer, but I've personally had more success selecting files using some other tool, and then passing along to RoboCopy to move the file(s).

that is certainly a solution but it would be ideal if I could do everything with just robocopy.  And it would be nice to better understand why it seems that some filter criteria work and some dont.

are cache, temp, and chrome in the root of c:\folder ? have you tried CDing into c:\folder?

no they are scattered, like in the example I gave

I don't think this is correct.  in my example, when I add "/XD chrome" it includes the folders containing "chrome".  It just seems to be somehow selective.  If I exclude "cache", it seems to be ignored

Through trial and error it seems I need to use a wild card and quote it.
/xd "cache" "temp"
seems to work
